# Premiere pro cc2015 preview lag

Tags: premiere, post-production

I tried editing a video shot on canon 750d @1080p 25fps.
I am using premiere pro cc2015 , windows 10 , Intel i3 and Intel HD 3000 graphics . When I import the video into premiere and play there is a red line on the timeline and the video lags.
Please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

1080p is a large resolution. Based on the information you've provided, you're likely hitting a hardware bottleneck and won't be able to do much to increase your performance.

Comment: Is is pre-rendering problem. Look at the link in the comment to question.